# InetAddress.getLocalHost() throws UnknownHostException

Tags: java, freebsd, opensolaris

I am testing our server-application (written Java) on different operating systems and thought that OpenSolaris (2008.11) would be the least troublesome due to the nice Java integration. Turns out I was wrong, as I end up with a UnknownHostException

```
try {
  computerName = InetAddress.getLocalHost().getHostName();
  if (computerName.indexOf(".") > -1)
    computerName = computerName.substring(0,
        computerName.indexOf(".")).toUpperCase();
} catch (UnknownHostException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
```

The output is:

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: desvearth01: desvearth01
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1353)
```

However, `nslookup desvearth01` returns the correct IP address, and `nslookup localhost` returns `127.0.0.1` as expected. Also, the same code works perfectly on FreeBSD. Is there anything special to OpenSolaris that I am not aware of?

Any hints appreciated, thanks.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

In good tradition, I can answer my own question once again:

It seems that `InetAddress.getLocalHost()` ignores the `/etc/resolv.conf`, but only looks at the `/etc/hosts` file (where I hadn't specified anything besides `localhost`). Adding the IP and hostname to this file solves the problem and the exception is gone.

---

Another answer is almost correct and I got hint from above and my problem get resolved...Thanks.

But to improve this, I am adding steps-by-steps changes, so that it will be helpful for even naive users.

Steps:

- Open `/etc/hosts`, the entries might look like below.

  ```
   127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4  
   ::1         localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
  ```
- You need to add one more line above of this by any editor like `vi` or `gedit` (e.g. `<your-machine-ip> <your-machine-name> localhost`).

  ```
   192.168.1.73 my_foo localhost
  ```

Now, overall file may look like this:

```
192.168.1.73 my_foo localhost
127.0.0.1    localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1          localhost localhost.localdomain localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

- Just save it and run again your Java code... your work is done.

Comment: If you encounter permission issues when trying to write to the hosts file, instructions here will help:http://decoding.wordpress.com/2009/04/06/how-to-edit-the-hosts-file-in-mac-os-x-leopard/

Comment: There is also a bug in OS X and java 7, details and workaround here https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/h2-database/DuIlTLN5KOo

Comment: Setting `127.0.0.1 localhost <hostname>` was sufficient for me

Comment: Found this too late.  Coded up a NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces() solution instead.

Comment: To get your hostname, you can use the `hostname` command from the terminal.

Comment: I had a similar issue under SuSE13 with Java8. Adding the host and ip to /etc/hosts helped, but afterwards nslookup <hostname> was not working anymore because of a timeout. So I removed 'localhost' from the end of the line and now nslookup as well as my Java application were working correctly.

Answer (score 11):

I use [`NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/NetworkInterface.html#getNetworkInterfaces--) as a fall back for when [`InetAddress.getLocalHost()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/InetAddress.html#getLocalHost--) throws an [`UnknownHostException`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/UnknownHostException.html).  Here's the code (without exception handling for clarity).

```
Enumeration<NetworkInterface> iterNetwork;
Enumeration<InetAddress> iterAddress;
NetworkInterface network;
InetAddress address;

iterNetwork = NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces();

while (iterNetwork.hasMoreElements())
{
   network = iterNetwork.nextElement();

   if (!network.isUp())
      continue;

   if (network.isLoopback())
      continue;

   iterAddress = network.getInetAddresses();

   while (iterAddress.hasMoreElements())
   {
      address = iterAddress.nextElement();

      if (address.isAnyLocalAddress())
         continue;

      if (address.isLoopbackAddress())
         continue;

      if (address.isMulticastAddress())
         continue;

      return address.getHostAddress();
   }
}
```

Other answers edit the `/etc/hosts` file.  This is error prone, brittle, may require root access and won't work on all OS's.

Answer (score 6):

On my amazon instance I was having the same issue, there was default DNS configuration issue. So to fix the issue I had done these steps -

> get your host name

```
$hostname
ip-10-122-16-169
```

> ping to hostname

```
$ping ip-10-122-16-169
ping: unknown host ip-10-122-16-169
```

> cat **/etc/hosts** file, you will get something like

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4
::1         localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

> now you just need to append your host name at the end of the fist line, so when you append it will look like

```
127.0.0.1   localhost localhost.localdomain localhost4 localhost4.localdomain4 ip-10-122-16-169
::1         localhost6 localhost6.localdomain6
```

> now you're ready to go, to check ping again the same hostname

```
$ping ip-10-122-16-169
PING localhost (127.0.0.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=1 ttl=255 time=0.018 ms
64 bytes from localhost (127.0.0.1): icmp_seq=2 ttl=255 time=0.024 ms
```

Answer (score 4):

Host lookups on Solaris uses `/etc/nsswitch.conf` so depending on what the 'hosts:' line says it determines if `/etc/hosts`, NIS, DNS and/or LDAP should be consulted.

If you only use hosts and DNS you should have this in `/etc/nsswitch.conf`:

```
hosts: files dns
```

The reason `nslookup desvearth01` works is because the `nslookup` command directly consults `/etc/resolv.conf`. If you want to do a better command line test, use the command:

```
getent hosts desvearth01
```

Answer (score 4):

This errors shows up when I changed the workstation name and tried start Glassfish 2. You also must rename the entry at /etc/hosts, something like this:

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.1.1       MyNewName
```

Answer (score 2):

Checkout */etc/hostname* then put your hostname to hosts file.

Answer (score 0):

I am having issues around this as well.  I need to do further testing, but it looks like
`NetworkInterface.getNetworkInterfaces()` can be more reliable.  I think that this does not do the lookup, but just grabs the IP.

I am using it as the 'next best' when the `getLocalHost()` fails.

Answer (score 0):

If you see this message than you need set hostname **WITH** `hostname superhost.domain` **COMMAND**!

After this, check which `/etc/hosts` file contain string like this `127.0.0.1 localhost`.

Also, check that command `uname -a` returns something like this:

> Linux **superhost.domain** 2.6.38-8-server #42-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 11 03:49:04 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

**NOT LIKE THIS!!!!**

> Linux **(none)** 2.6.38-8-server #42-Ubuntu SMP Mon Apr 11 03:49:04 UTC 2011 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

Answer (score 0):

Another option is in this post (in fact, what is in your /etc/sysconfig/network file for your hostname...by changing it to an FQDN name fixes this issue).

[java getLocalHost() UnknownHostException /etc/hosts file differs linux api?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12159444/java-getlocalhost-unknownhostexception-etc-hosts-file-differs-linux-api)