# Why does this usage of InetAddress.getLocalHost() work okay with Java 6 but fails with Java 7 on OSX

Tags: java, macos, java-7, osx-mavericks

It works okay for me but on OSX Mavericks for a particular customer InetAddress.getLocalHost() is failing with Java 7 although it works okay with Java 6 with the following exception

```
java.net.UnknownHostException: rupert: rupert: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1466)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: rupert: nodename nor servname provided, or not known
    at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
    at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:894)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1286)
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1462)
```

Is this by design ?

**Update**

Looks to be a known bug fixed in Java 8

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-7180557

Comment: I'd say this is environmental. Their hostname is being looked up in DNS and is not being found. It does work in the Java 6 VM but obviously the lookup mechanism for Java 7 has changed. if I change my hostname using `sudo hostname rupert`, and then run some simple test code I get the same error.

Comment: +1 to the comment that this is a known bug in Java that was fixed in 1.8. I can confirm that running this under Oracle Java 1.7.0_72 (latest as of this writing) on my Mac OS X 10.10 (Yosemite) environment fails with the reported exception, but as expected under Oracle Java 1.8.0_25 (latest as of this writing). I believe it was working properly under Mac OS X 10.9 (Mavericks) before I upgraded. I suspect that the upgrade tweaked something very particular about the networking configuration since the original report mentions Mavericks and not Yosemite.

Comment: Is it expected for the fix to be backported to those who require JDK 7 rather than 8? I do not see this mentioned in the bug reported

Comment: From that bug report appears it was also fixed in 7u85 but then it appears they only released up through 7u79 publically <sigh>.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am guessing you will find the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881546/inetaddress-getlocalhost-throws-unknownhostexception) - even though that question is about Solaris, both Mac OS X and Solaris are Unix operating systems.

Comment: Yes, you are right I suppose this begs the question how do you get the local ipa address in Java then, and also how do you get the mac address as I was using InetAddress address = java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost();
            NetworkInterface ni = NetworkInterface.getByInetAddress(address);

Comment: If this is a duplicate question you should vote to close, not link to the duplicate in an answer.

Comment: Even if I don't know if it is actually a duplicate? It was just a guess, otherwise I would have voted.

Answer (score 7):

Add the {yourhostname} part of this to `/etc/hosts`

e.g.

```
127.0.0.1       localhost {yourhostname}
```

and the problem disappears.

Comment: You can get your hostname by entering the command `hostname` in terminal and seeing what it returns.

Comment: Finally an answer that at least works around the problem, thanks! (as a note for followers, this I believe is related to the fact that its doing some kind of reverse hostname lookup http://apple.stackexchange.com/q/30552/25085)