# API Manger fails to start in a Remote Server

Tags: wso2, wso2-esb

I am trying to run APIM 1.6.0 in a remote server. It gives following exception - http://pastebin.com/HTAsbpsQ. Is it a configuration fault in APIM or problem in the server configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

If you have changed the HostName and MgtHostName properties in carbon.xml try first by giving the IP of the server. It seems the server is bound to an unresolvable host name.

Comment: I changed this but same happens,  <!--HostName>www.wso2.org</HostName-->

Comment: Actually the problem is with CentOS. Same kind of problem s explained in https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-2002 and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881546/inetaddress-getlocalhost-throws-unknownhostexception. I have resolved the problem using the above links.