# Kafka - shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer), problems with starting Kafka-Server-Start

Tags: java, scala, apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

I'll start from the beginning. I have openSuse 13.2, i also have jdk_1.7.0_51, scala-2.11.4 and gradle-2.2.1. I have downloaded source of kafka-0.8.2-bet-src and run ./gradlew commands as they where written in readme file. All commands where ran with success, except test (93% where successful, 19 failed) btw i got my releaseTarGz (kafka_2.11-0.8.2-beta.tgz). So everything goes right, i run zookeeper and it's starting right, but when i run kafka-server-start i get:

```
[2014-12-09 14:27:12,496] INFO Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2014-12-09 14:27:12,496] INFO Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2014-12-09 14:27:12,496] INFO Client environment:java.compiler=<NA> (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2014-12-09 14:27:12,496] INFO Client environment:os.name=Linux (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2014-12-09 14:27:12,497] INFO Client environment:os.arch=amd64 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2014-12-09 14:27:12,497] INFO Client environment:os.version=3.16.6-2-desktop (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2014-12-09 14:27:12,497] INFO Client environment:user.name=root (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2014-12-09 14:27:12,497] INFO Client environment:user.home=/root (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2014-12-09 14:27:12,497] INFO Client environment:user.dir=/home/stefan/kafka_2.11-0.8.2-beta (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2014-12-09 14:27:12,499] INFO Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=6000 watcher=org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient@4758af63 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2014-12-09 14:27:12,542] INFO Opening socket connection to server localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2014-12-09 14:27:12,550] INFO Socket connection established to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181, initiating session (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2014-12-09 14:27:12,582] INFO Session establishment complete on server localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181, sessionid = 0x14a2f1b690f0002, negotiated timeout = 6000 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2014-12-09 14:27:12,586] INFO zookeeper state changed (SyncConnected) (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient)
[2014-12-09 14:27:12,723] INFO Loading logs. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2014-12-09 14:27:12,746] INFO Logs loading complete. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2014-12-09 14:27:12,752] INFO Starting log cleanup with a period of 60000 ms. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2014-12-09 14:27:12,760] INFO Starting log flusher with a default period of 9223372036854775807 ms. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2014-12-09 14:27:12,813] INFO Awaiting socket connections on 0.0.0.0:9092. (kafka.network.Acceptor)
[2014-12-09 14:27:12,814] INFO [Socket Server on Broker 0], Started (kafka.network.SocketServer)
[2014-12-09 14:27:12,950] INFO Will not load MX4J, mx4j-tools.jar is not in the classpath (kafka.utils.Mx4jLoader$)
[2014-12-09 14:27:13,078] INFO 0 successfully elected as leader (kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector)
[2014-12-09 14:27:13,263] FATAL [Kafka Server 0], Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
java.net.UnknownHostException: linux-pic4.site: linux-pic4.site: Name or service not known
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1473)
        at kafka.server.KafkaHealthcheck.register(KafkaHealthcheck.scala:59)
        at kafka.server.KafkaHealthcheck.startup(KafkaHealthcheck.scala:45)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:124)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:28)
        at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:46)
        at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: linux-pic4.site: Name or service not known
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
        at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:901)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1293)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1469)
        ... 6 more
[2014-12-09 14:27:13,270] INFO [Kafka Server 0], shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2014-12-09 14:27:13,289] INFO Deregistered broker 0 at path /brokers/ids/0. (kafka.utils.ZkUtils$)
[2014-12-09 14:27:13,295] INFO [Socket Server on Broker 0], Shutting down (kafka.network.SocketServer)
[2014-12-09 14:27:13,323] INFO [Socket Server on Broker 0], Shutdown completed (kafka.network.SocketServer)
[2014-12-09 14:27:13,325] INFO [Kafka Request Handler on Broker 0], shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaRequestHandlerPool)
[2014-12-09 14:27:13,406] INFO [Kafka Request Handler on Broker 0], shut down completely (kafka.server.KafkaRequestHandlerPool)
[2014-12-09 14:27:13,492] INFO New leader is 0 (kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector$LeaderChangeListener)
[2014-12-09 14:27:13,735] INFO [Replica Manager on Broker 0]: Shut down (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)
[2014-12-09 14:27:13,736] INFO [ReplicaFetcherManager on broker 0] shutting down (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherManager)
[2014-12-09 14:27:13,739] INFO [ReplicaFetcherManager on broker 0] shutdown completed (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherManager)
[2014-12-09 14:27:13,746] INFO [Replica Manager on Broker 0]: Shut down completely (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)
[2014-12-09 14:27:13,747] INFO Shutting down. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2014-12-09 14:27:13,765] INFO Shutdown complete. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2014-12-09 14:27:13,775] INFO Terminate ZkClient event thread. (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkEventThread)
[2014-12-09 14:27:13,796] INFO Session: 0x14a2f1b690f0002 closed (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2014-12-09 14:27:13,797] INFO EventThread shut down (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2014-12-09 14:27:13,797] INFO [Kafka Server 0], shut down completed (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2014-12-09 14:27:13,799] FATAL Fatal error during KafkaServerStartable startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable)
java.net.UnknownHostException: linux-pic4.site: linux-pic4.site: Name or service not known
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1473)
        at kafka.server.KafkaHealthcheck.register(KafkaHealthcheck.scala:59)
        at kafka.server.KafkaHealthcheck.startup(KafkaHealthcheck.scala:45)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:124)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:28)
        at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:46)
        at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: linux-pic4.site: Name or service not known
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
        at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:901)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1293)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1469)
        ... 6 more
[2014-12-09 14:27:13,802] INFO [Kafka Server 0], shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2014-12-09 14:27:12,496] INFO Client environment:java.library.path=/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2014-12-09 14:27:12,496] INFO Client environment:java.io.tmpdir=/tmp (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2014-12-09 14:27:12,496] INFO Client environment:java.compiler=<NA> (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2014-12-09 14:27:12,496] INFO Client environment:os.name=Linux (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2014-12-09 14:27:12,497] INFO Client environment:os.arch=amd64 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2014-12-09 14:27:12,497] INFO Client environment:os.version=3.16.6-2-desktop (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2014-12-09 14:27:12,497] INFO Client environment:user.name=root (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2014-12-09 14:27:12,497] INFO Client environment:user.home=/root (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2014-12-09 14:27:12,497] INFO Client environment:user.dir=/home/stefan/kafka_2.11-0.8.2-beta (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2014-12-09 14:27:12,499] INFO Initiating client connection, connectString=localhost:2181 sessionTimeout=6000 watcher=org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient@4758af63 (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2014-12-09 14:27:12,542] INFO Opening socket connection to server localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181. Will not attempt to authenticate using SASL (unknown error) (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2014-12-09 14:27:12,550] INFO Socket connection established to localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181, initiating session (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2014-12-09 14:27:12,582] INFO Session establishment complete on server localhost/0:0:0:0:0:0:0:1:2181, sessionid = 0x14a2f1b690f0002, negotiated timeout = 6000 (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2014-12-09 14:27:12,586] INFO zookeeper state changed (SyncConnected) (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkClient)
[2014-12-09 14:27:12,723] INFO Loading logs. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2014-12-09 14:27:12,746] INFO Logs loading complete. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2014-12-09 14:27:12,752] INFO Starting log cleanup with a period of 60000 ms. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2014-12-09 14:27:12,760] INFO Starting log flusher with a default period of 9223372036854775807 ms. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2014-12-09 14:27:12,813] INFO Awaiting socket connections on 0.0.0.0:9092. (kafka.network.Acceptor)
[2014-12-09 14:27:12,814] INFO [Socket Server on Broker 0], Started (kafka.network.SocketServer)
[2014-12-09 14:27:12,950] INFO Will not load MX4J, mx4j-tools.jar is not in the classpath (kafka.utils.Mx4jLoader$)
[2014-12-09 14:27:13,078] INFO 0 successfully elected as leader (kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector)
[2014-12-09 14:27:13,263] FATAL [Kafka Server 0], Fatal error during KafkaServer startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
java.net.UnknownHostException: linux-pic4.site: linux-pic4.site: Name or service not known
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1473)
        at kafka.server.KafkaHealthcheck.register(KafkaHealthcheck.scala:59)
        at kafka.server.KafkaHealthcheck.startup(KafkaHealthcheck.scala:45)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:124)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:28)
        at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:46)
        at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: linux-pic4.site: Name or service not known
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
        at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:901)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1293)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1469)
        ... 6 more
[2014-12-09 14:27:13,270] INFO [Kafka Server 0], shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2014-12-09 14:27:13,289] INFO Deregistered broker 0 at path /brokers/ids/0. (kafka.utils.ZkUtils$)
[2014-12-09 14:27:13,295] INFO [Socket Server on Broker 0], Shutting down (kafka.network.SocketServer)
[2014-12-09 14:27:13,323] INFO [Socket Server on Broker 0], Shutdown completed (kafka.network.SocketServer)
[2014-12-09 14:27:13,325] INFO [Kafka Request Handler on Broker 0], shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaRequestHandlerPool)
[2014-12-09 14:27:13,406] INFO [Kafka Request Handler on Broker 0], shut down completely (kafka.server.KafkaRequestHandlerPool)
[2014-12-09 14:27:13,492] INFO New leader is 0 (kafka.server.ZookeeperLeaderElector$LeaderChangeListener)
[2014-12-09 14:27:13,735] INFO [Replica Manager on Broker 0]: Shut down (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)
[2014-12-09 14:27:13,736] INFO [ReplicaFetcherManager on broker 0] shutting down (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherManager)
[2014-12-09 14:27:13,739] INFO [ReplicaFetcherManager on broker 0] shutdown completed (kafka.server.ReplicaFetcherManager)
[2014-12-09 14:27:13,746] INFO [Replica Manager on Broker 0]: Shut down completely (kafka.server.ReplicaManager)
[2014-12-09 14:27:13,747] INFO Shutting down. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2014-12-09 14:27:13,765] INFO Shutdown complete. (kafka.log.LogManager)
[2014-12-09 14:27:13,775] INFO Terminate ZkClient event thread. (org.I0Itec.zkclient.ZkEventThread)
[2014-12-09 14:27:13,796] INFO Session: 0x14a2f1b690f0002 closed (org.apache.zookeeper.ZooKeeper)
[2014-12-09 14:27:13,797] INFO EventThread shut down (org.apache.zookeeper.ClientCnxn)
[2014-12-09 14:27:13,797] INFO [Kafka Server 0], shut down completed (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
[2014-12-09 14:27:13,799] FATAL Fatal error during KafkaServerStartable startup. Prepare to shutdown (kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable)
java.net.UnknownHostException: linux-pic4.site: linux-pic4.site: Name or service not known
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1473)
        at kafka.server.KafkaHealthcheck.register(KafkaHealthcheck.scala:59)
        at kafka.server.KafkaHealthcheck.startup(KafkaHealthcheck.scala:45)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServer.startup(KafkaServer.scala:124)
        at kafka.server.KafkaServerStartable.startup(KafkaServerStartable.scala:28)
        at kafka.Kafka$.main(Kafka.scala:46)
        at kafka.Kafka.main(Kafka.scala)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: linux-pic4.site: Name or service not known
        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Native Method)
        at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:901)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1293)
        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1469)
        ... 6 more
[2014-12-09 14:27:13,802] INFO [Kafka Server 0], shutting down (kafka.server.KafkaServer)
```

This is my server.properties file:

```
# Licensed to the Apache Software Foundation (ASF) under one or more
# contributor license agreements.  See the NOTICE file distributed with
# this work for additional information regarding copyright ownership.
# The ASF licenses this file to You under the Apache License, Version 2.0
# (the "License"); you may not use this file except in compliance with
# the License.  You may obtain a copy of the License at
# 
#    http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0
# 
# Unless required by applicable law or agreed to in writing, software
# distributed under the License is distributed on an "AS IS" BASIS,
# WITHOUT WARRANTIES OR CONDITIONS OF ANY KIND, either express or implied.
# See the License for the specific language governing permissions and
# limitations under the License.
# see kafka.server.KafkaConfig for additional details and defaults

############################# Server Basics #############################

# The id of the broker. This must be set to a unique integer for each broker.
broker.id=0

############################# Socket Server Settings #############################

# The port the socket server listens on
port=9092

# Hostname the broker will bind to. If not set, the server will bind to all interfaces
#host.name=localhost

# Hostname the broker will advertise to producers and consumers. If not set, it uses the
# value for "host.name" if configured.  Otherwise, it will use the value returned from
# java.net.InetAddress.getCanonicalHostName().
#advertised.host.name=<hostname routable by clients>

# The port to publish to ZooKeeper for clients to use. If this is not set,
# it will publish the same port that the broker binds to.
#advertised.port=<port accessible by clients>

# The number of threads handling network requests
num.network.threads=3

# The number of threads doing disk I/O
num.io.threads=8

# The send buffer (SO_SNDBUF) used by the socket server
socket.send.buffer.bytes=102400

# The receive buffer (SO_RCVBUF) used by the socket server
socket.receive.buffer.bytes=65536

# The maximum size of a request that the socket server will accept (protection against OOM)
socket.request.max.bytes=104857600


############################# Log Basics #############################

# A comma seperated list of directories under which to store log files
log.dirs=/tmp/kafka-logs

# The default number of log partitions per topic. More partitions allow greater
# parallelism for consumption, but this will also result in more files across
# the brokers.
num.partitions=1

# The number of threads per data directory to be used for log recovery at startup and flushing at shutdown.
# This value is recommended to be increased for installations with data dirs located in RAID array.
num.recovery.threads.per.data.dir=1

############################# Log Flush Policy #############################

# Messages are immediately written to the filesystem but by default we only fsync() to sync
# the OS cache lazily. The following configurations control the flush of data to disk. 
# There are a few important trade-offs here:
#    1. Durability: Unflushed data may be lost if you are not using replication.
#    2. Latency: Very large flush intervals may lead to latency spikes when the flush does occur as there will be a lot of data to flush.
#    3. Throughput: The flush is generally the most expensive operation, and a small flush interval may lead to exceessive seeks. 
# The settings below allow one to configure the flush policy to flush data after a period of time or
# every N messages (or both). This can be done globally and overridden on a per-topic basis.

# The number of messages to accept before forcing a flush of data to disk
#log.flush.interval.messages=10000

# The maximum amount of time a message can sit in a log before we force a flush
#log.flush.interval.ms=1000

############################# Log Retention Policy #############################

# The following configurations control the disposal of log segments. The policy can
# be set to delete segments after a period of time, or after a given size has accumulated.
# A segment will be deleted whenever *either* of these criteria are met. Deletion always happens
# from the end of the log.

# The minimum age of a log file to be eligible for deletion
log.retention.hours=168

# A size-based retention policy for logs. Segments are pruned from the log as long as the remaining
# segments don't drop below log.retention.bytes.
#log.retention.bytes=1073741824

# The maximum size of a log segment file. When this size is reached a new log segment will be created.
log.segment.bytes=1073741824

# The interval at which log segments are checked to see if they can be deleted according 
# to the retention policies
log.retention.check.interval.ms=300000

# By default the log cleaner is disabled and the log retention policy will default to just delete segments after their retention expires.
# If log.cleaner.enable=true is set the cleaner will be enabled and individual logs can then be marked for log compaction.
log.cleaner.enable=false

############################# Zookeeper #############################

# Zookeeper connection string (see zookeeper docs for details).
# This is a comma separated host:port pairs, each corresponding to a zk
# server. e.g. "127.0.0.1:3000,127.0.0.1:3001,127.0.0.1:3002".
# You can also append an optional chroot string to the urls to specify the
# root directory for all kafka znodes.
zookeeper.connect=localhost:2181

# Timeout in ms for connecting to zookeeper
zookeeper.connection.timeout.ms=2000
```

And my /etc/hosts file:

```
#
# hosts         This file describes a number of hostname-to-address
#               mappings for the TCP/IP subsystem.  It is mostly
#               used at boot time, when no name servers are running.
#               On small systems, this file can be used instead of a
#               "named" name server.
# Syntax:
#    
# IP-Address  Full-Qualified-Hostname  Short-Hostname
#

127.0.0.1       localhost

# special IPv6 addresses
::1             localhost ipv6-localhost ipv6-loopback

fe00::0         ipv6-localnet

ff00::0         ipv6-mcastprefix
ff02::1         ipv6-allnodes
ff02::2         ipv6-allrouters
ff02::3         ipv6-allhosts
```

Could anyone help me?

Comment: did you try using Kafka 0.8.1.1 instead of 0.8.2-beta?

Comment: I did and i had the same problem, but when i tried to run Kafka on windows and I succeeded. It's working, i assume that some of my ports on Suse are occupied and that is the reason why tests and kafka-server is not running, can somebody help me to see which ports are busy and how to free them.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You need to add your hostname to /etc/hosts:
127.0.0.1 localhost linux-pic4.site

See here for deeper explanation:
[InetAddress.getLocalHost() throws UnknownHostException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881546/inetaddress-getlocalhost-throws-unknownhostexception)

Comment: Thanks. Your tip helped me. I checked my /etc/hosts file and found a line
that contained 127.0.0.1 localhost without my machine's name. I appended new line contained hostname  127.0.0.1 localhost <name_of_my_server> and kafka have started.

Answer (score 3):

Recommends use host.name property on the server.properties configuration file.

Hostname the broker will bind to. If not set, the server will bind to all interfaces

```
host.name=yourhostname
```

or

```
host.name=localhost
```

Comment: `host.name` is [deprecated](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation.html#brokerconfigs) - as are `advertised.host.name` and `advertised.port`

Answer (score 0):

Copy the path of the Kafka folder. Now go to config inside kafka folder and open zookeeper.properties file. Copy the path against the field dataDir and add /zookeeper-data to the path. Now in the same folder config open server.properties and scroll down to log.dirs and paste the path. To the path add /kafka-logs