# Eclipse Mars: Startup Error: UnknownHostException

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-mars, unknown-host, startup-error

I am getting this error at Eclipse Mars Startup:

---

### STATUS

```
pluginId            org.eclipse.rse.core
pluginVersion       3.3.100.201407181907
code                0
severity            4
message             Unexpected Exception
fingerprint         cce9c498
```

> Exception:java.net.UnknownHostException: amrit-Latitude-E5450: amrit-Latitude-E5450: Name or service not known
>        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1473)
>        at org.eclipse.rse.core.RSECorePlugin.getLocalMachineName(RSECorePlugin.java:265)
>        at org.eclipse.rse.core.RSEPreferencesManager.getDefaultPrivateSystemProfileName(RSEPreferencesManager.java:358)
>        at org.eclipse.rse.core.RSEPreferencesManager.initDefaults(RSEPreferencesManager.java:337)
>        at org.eclipse.rse.internal.core.RSEPreferenceInitializer.initializeDefaultPreferences(RSEPreferenceInitializer.java:23)
>        at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper$1.run(PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper.java:300)
>        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
>        at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper.runInitializer(PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper.java:303)
>        at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper.applyRuntimeDefaults(PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper.java:131)
>        at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferencesService.applyRuntimeDefaults(PreferencesService.java:368)
>        at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.DefaultPreferences.applyRuntimeDefaults(DefaultPreferences.java:221)
>        at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.DefaultPreferences.load(DefaultPreferences.java:274)
>        at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.create(EclipsePreferences.java:409)
>        at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.internalNode(EclipsePreferences.java:670)
>        at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.DefaultPreferences.node(DefaultPreferences.java:147)
>        at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.legacy.PreferenceForwarder.getDefaultPreferences(PreferenceForwarder.java:134)
>        at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.legacy.PreferenceForwarder.getInt(PreferenceForwarder.java:488)
>        at org.eclipse.rse.logging.Logger.initialize(Logger.java:249)
>        at org.eclipse.rse.logging.Logger.(Logger.java:135)
>        at org.eclipse.rse.logging.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:45)
>        at org.eclipse.rse.core.RSECorePlugin.getLogger(RSECorePlugin.java:392)
>        at org.eclipse.rse.internal.core.RSEInitJob.(RSEInitJob.java:133)
>        at org.eclipse.rse.internal.core.RSEInitJob.(RSEInitJob.java:65)
>        at org.eclipse.rse.core.RSECorePlugin.waitForInitCompletion(RSECorePlugin.java:142)
>        at org.eclipse.rse.internal.ui.RSEUIInitJob.run(RSEUIInitJob.java:32)
>        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)
>   Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: amrit-Latitude-E5450: Name or service not known
>        at java.net.Inet6AddressImpl.lookupAllHostAddr(Inet6AddressImpl.java:-2)
>        at java.net.InetAddress$1.lookupAllHostAddr(InetAddress.java:901)
>        at java.net.InetAddress.getAddressesFromNameService(InetAddress.java:1293)
>        at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost(InetAddress.java:1469)
>        at org.eclipse.rse.core.RSECorePlugin.getLocalMachineName(RSECorePlugin.java:265)
>        at org.eclipse.rse.core.RSEPreferencesManager.getDefaultPrivateSystemProfileName(RSEPreferencesManager.java:358)
>        at org.eclipse.rse.core.RSEPreferencesManager.initDefaults(RSEPreferencesManager.java:337)
>        at org.eclipse.rse.internal.core.RSEPreferenceInitializer.initializeDefaultPreferences(RSEPreferenceInitializer.java:23)
>        at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper$1.run(PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper.java:300)
>        at org.eclipse.core.runtime.SafeRunner.run(SafeRunner.java:42)
>        at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper.runInitializer(PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper.java:303)
>        at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper.applyRuntimeDefaults(PreferenceServiceRegistryHelper.java:131)
>        at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.PreferencesService.applyRuntimeDefaults(PreferencesService.java:368)
>        at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.DefaultPreferences.applyRuntimeDefaults(DefaultPreferences.java:221)
>        at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.DefaultPreferences.load(DefaultPreferences.java:274)
>        at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.create(EclipsePreferences.java:409)
>        at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.EclipsePreferences.internalNode(EclipsePreferences.java:670)
>        at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.DefaultPreferences.node(DefaultPreferences.java:147)
>        at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.legacy.PreferenceForwarder.getDefaultPreferences(PreferenceForwarder.java:134)
>        at org.eclipse.core.internal.preferences.legacy.PreferenceForwarder.getInt(PreferenceForwarder.java:488)
>        at org.eclipse.rse.logging.Logger.initialize(Logger.java:249)
>        at org.eclipse.rse.logging.Logger.(Logger.java:135)
>        at org.eclipse.rse.logging.LoggerFactory.getLogger(LoggerFactory.java:45)
>        at org.eclipse.rse.core.RSECorePlugin.getLogger(RSECorePlugin.java:392)
>        at org.eclipse.rse.internal.core.RSEInitJob.(RSEInitJob.java:133)
>        at org.eclipse.rse.internal.core.RSEInitJob.(RSEInitJob.java:65)
>        at org.eclipse.rse.core.RSECorePlugin.waitForInitCompletion(RSECorePlugin.java:142)
>        at org.eclipse.rse.internal.ui.RSEUIInitJob.run(RSEUIInitJob.java:32)
>        at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:55)

---

### REPORT

```
anonymousId         efee7f97-68b2-4225-b42c-3dcc4515ef81
name                Amrit
email               amrit.sarkar@snapdeal.com
comment             
eclipseBuildId      4.5.0.I20150603-2000
eclipseProduct      org.eclipse.epp.package.jee.product
javaRuntimeVersion  1.7.0_79-b14
osgiWs              gtk
osgiOs              Linux
osgiOsVersion       3.16.0
osgiArch            x86_64
logMessage          false
ignoreSimilar       false
```

---

### BUNDLES

```
name                org.eclipse.core.jobs
version             3.7.0.v20150330-2103

name                org.eclipse.core.runtime
version             3.11.0.v20150405-1723

name                org.eclipse.rse.core
version             3.3.100.201407181907

name                org.eclipse.rse
version             3.5.0.201403100950

name                org.eclipse.rse.ui
version             3.3.100.201503112018
```

Anyone with any Clue?

Comment: Can you reformat your code and error to give us what we need to understand your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem and I added the hostname within the hosts file (/etc/hosts) at the end of the line that says "127.0.0.1 localhost". You should end with something like this "127.0.0.1 localhost hostname" and then the error has gone.

I identified the solution from the post: [InetAddress.getLocalHost() throws UnknownHostException](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881546/inetaddress-getlocalhost-throws-unknownhostexception)

Please try with the tip I mention or try using the solutions proposed in the mentioned post.