# Inetaddress.getLocalHost() UnknownHostException Windows 8

Tags: java, spring, elasticsearch, inetaddress

I am attempting to use Elastic Search in a Spring program. Currently I am trying to create a Transport Client as per [this guide](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-api/5.1/transport-client.html). Unfortunately the `InetAddress.getByName("localhost")` is giving me an

> unhandled exception type UnknownHostException

I have also tried using `InetAddress.getLocalHost()` and have received the same error.

I am on a Windows 8 machine and I have changed my host file as detailed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881546/inetaddress-getlocalhost-throws-unknownhostexception). If anyone has any ideas please let me know. Thank you.

Comment: I believe that under some conditions Windows will not start parts of its networking stack. Do you have an active wifi or wired network connection at that time?

Comment: Yes I have an active wifi connection when I run this. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Unfortunately not, iirc the phenomenon I was thinking of, occurs when there are no external network connections.