# Spring Cloud Contract UnknownHostException

Tags: spring-boot, amazon-ec2, groovy, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-contract

Im developing a project using spring-cloud-contract and works perfect on local, however, when i run the project in jenkins on aws throw a UnknownHostException.

first show this:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin:2.2.2.RELEASE:generateTests (default-generateTests) on project proxy-api: Execution default-generateTests of goal org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin:2.2.2.RELEASE:generateTests failed: An API incompatibility was encountered while executing org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin:2.2.2.RELEASE:generateTests: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError: null
```

review i found this:

```
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: ip-10-151-82-104: ip-10-151-82-104: Name or service not known
    at java.net.InetAddress.getLocalHost (InetAddress.java:1642)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.extension.responsetemplating.helpers.HostnameHelper.<clinit> (HostnameHelper.java:31)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.extension.responsetemplating.helpers.WireMockHelpers$5.<init> (WireMockHelpers.java:62)
    at com.github.tomakehurst.wiremock.extension.responsetemplating.helpers.WireMockHelpers.<clinit> (WireMockHelpers.java:61)
```

i config the plugin to use Local, without result:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-contract-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud-contract.version}</version>
                <extensions>true</extensions>
                <configuration>
                    <testFramework>JUNIT5</testFramework>
                    <testMode>WEBTESTCLIENT</testMode>
                    <packageWithBaseClasses>com.proxy.api</packageWithBaseClasses>
                    <contractsMode>LOCAL</contractsMode>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

**Update:**
I found an approach adding ip to /etc/hosts file like mention on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1881546/inetaddress-getlocalhost-throws-unknownhostexception) ,however , first talking with devops team mention that this is not a good aproach since ip could change. And seccond and most important ***why is ip needed?*** since the only thing i want is do test.